# What is double colon in yaml ? I'm seeing in AWS Cloud Formation

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm sorry if this is a noob question for you but I seriously don't understand the double colon here. What does it mean ?

"Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"

I understand basic YAML syntax and couldn't find an explanation for this.

Comment: I don't think the double colon is yaml syntax. It is just a part of the string.

Comment: Yes, seeing a comment below and your thought, makes sense. Thanks

Comment: it also means that you haven't gone through a first cloudformation tutorial

Comment: well I just started using it, wasn't difficult

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The double colon aren't related to YAML. In fact, they've been around since the beginning of CloudFormation in JSON. *AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName* is just the way AWS decided to name their resource types. They could have gone for *AWS_EC2_KeyPair_KeyName* or anything else for that matter.

Comment: Oh thank you for this. Now i had a look on CF template and i can make sense of this line. Thanks alot.

Comment: Worth mentioning that :: is a 'scope resolution operator', commonly used in programming languages such as C++ and Java.